# Usage of "do by"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-usage

By 'do by' :-

- You've did wrong/ill by me.
- You've done ill by him by prejudging him.
- You're doing ill by me.
- You've did me ill by by what you groundlessly accused me of.
- Sir, you have done me wrong by.

Would these examples work, do they sound weird?
I know there is hard done by but I need a verb.

All suggestions are much welcome

Comment: Apart from the "You've *did* wrong" which should be "You've ***done*** wrong." in all your cases, there's nothing wrong with "You've done wrong by me."  "You have done me wrong by" is an incomplete sentence- *done me wrong by <what>*?

Comment: @Jim, I think what he/she wants in the last is example is "Sir, you have done wrong by me".

Answer (score 0):

[TfD defines "do by" as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/do+by)

> To behave with respect to; deal with: *The children have done well by their aged parents.*

However, as [Cambridge notes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/do), only a limited set of adverbs are typically used after "do" in this construction; "wrong" and "ill" are both somewhat unusual here, particularly since you can say "did someone wrong" instead. Note that "to do someone wrong" is a *separate* idiom.

But let's go through these, using the word "wrong":

> You've did wrong by me.

"You've did" is never valid; you use the past participle *done* in the perfect tense.

> You've done wrong by him by prejudging him.

This is perfectly valid.

> You're doing wrong by me.

Likewise, valid.

> You've did me wrong by by what you groundlessly accused me of.

As above, "you've did" is never valid. Also, the rest of the sentence doesn't make any sense.

> Sir, you have done me wrong by.

"To do someone wrong" is a separate idiom; you can't combine it with the "by" of "to do wrong by someone."

Answer (score -1):

They all sound weird and ungrammatical.

> I need a verb.

How about **[wronged](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrong)**?

> You've wronged me.

Similar to this is **doing wrong**:

> You've done him wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate the phrasal verb 'do by', so how come?

Comment: To be *hard done by* is a specialized phrase that's not readily adaptable to other uses. You could perhaps adapt "You've did wrong/ill by me" to "I feel hard done by", but that's about it.